Heston Stochastic Vol and the local volatility in Gatheral's Book
I have been reading Gatheral's Book "The volatility Surface" and in the case of Chapter 4 ( The Heston Nandi model), the author provides the following graph.

It shows that implied volatilities are the same when using the Heston Model Formula and When Using an approximation of the local Volatility in the case of the Heston Model. It seems that the author claim that we have this when spot/variance correlation is equal to one as he obtains only one source of randomness.
And This is the closed formula obtained for local volatility in gatheral's book.

Does this means that given a set of parameters of the heston model, I get the same prices if If I use the Heston Formula and if I solve the PDE using the closed formula of the local volatility that I showed above ? I tried to test this using Monte-Carlo but it doesn't seem to work.
Thank you very much.

Yes, in theory (at least approximately depending on how good the closed approximative formula is) and if you use the same assumptions on the parameters in both cases.
In practice you need the partial derivatives of the option prices. So you first need to construct accurate option prices and then approximate the derivatives.
